# Average of two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, average

I wanted to take average of two columns and display in a new column something like this:

```
+-+--+--+--+--------+--------+
|A|B |C |D |AVG(B/C)|AVG(C/B)|
+-+--+--+--+--------+--------+
|S|23|34|56|        |        |
+-+--+--+--+--------+--------+
|T|45|6 |79|        |        |
+-+--+--+--+--------+--------+
```

So, as shown above, I needed to take the each row values and perform B/C and then take the average accordingly to display it in a new column.

I wanted to do this in SQL query. Is it possible to perform this in a SQL command? I know the `AVG()` function does take the average of a column but how can I do `B/C` and then take the average? also if I need to take the average of B and C as well how can i do that.

This is what I am doing right now:

```
Select A,B,C,D FROM tableTest where A='S';
```

I now have to take the average of corresponding and also have another two columns additionally in the query to show the respective results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give it a try:

```
SELECT A, AVG((B+C)/2) as bc, AVG((C+B)/2) as cb
FROM tableTest
WHERE A = 'S'
GROUP BY A
```

Comment: Thank you MarcinJuraszek, its working, but if I need to take avg of two columns not column1/column2 then how should I do that, just `AVG(Col1,Col2)` would work?

Comment: Applying simple math `AVG` of two columns should be the same as `AVG((Col1 + Col2) /2)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Right, but I thought may be the `AVG` inbuilt function of `SQL` just needs the arguments as column name and it does the average of both. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A`VG(col1/col2)` is not the same as `AVG((col1+col2/2)`.

How about using `GROUP BY`?

> SELECT city, "average money spend:", AVG( sales-profit/
> number-of-customer)  FROM Sales GROUP BY City

Then better use

> SUM(sales-profit)/SUM(number-of-customers)

or use

> AVG(sales-profit)/AVG(number-of-customers)

(but this is less pragmatic (that is understandability is less).

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to use `AVG` to get the average between 2 columns, you can do a math operation:

```
Select A,B,C,D,(B+C)/2 AS BCAvg
FROM tableTest 
WHERE A = 'S';
```

Which offers a slight advantage in simplicity, it doesn't require using the AVG function or a `GROUP BY` clause.